# How to limit data on line chart to latest month on QlikSense?

Tags: dashboard, qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I'm trying to create a line chart with the data for only the current month. My date field is called `PurchaseDate`. I use this also for the 'Date Range Picker' widget in my dashboard. My dimension is `PurchaseDate` and my measure is `PurchaseVolume`. My data looks like this:

[image]

How can I set a condition to use only the current/latest month for my line chart?

I tried using a variable like this:
`CurrentMonth = Max(PurchaseDate)`

And I set the expression in my line chart to:
Dimension: `if(CurrentMonth, PurchaseDate)`
Measure: `if(CurrentMonth, PurchaseVolume)`

But here, my values keep changing according to the selected date on the Date Ranger Picker. How can I set the line chart for only the latest month (so the dimension will have each day of the latest month, which in this case will be Jan 2022) independent of the Date Range Picker? Is there a way I can set the calculation condition?

Comment: Just to confirm. The chart should always show the last possible month (from `PurchaseDate` field) no matter what is selected (or not) in the `PurshaseDate` field?

Comment: That's right, I want to have an overview of the latest month that's in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use set analysis in your expression to filter `PurchaseDate`(s) which are between the [MonthStart](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/monthstart.htm) and [MonthEnd](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/monthsend.htm) of the max possible month:

`Sum({<PurchaseDate={">=$(=Monthstart(max({1}PurchaseDate)))<=$(=monthend(max({1}PurchaseDate)))"} >} PurchaseVolume)`

The interesting path is the set analysis:

`PurchaseDate={">=$(=MonthStart(max({1}PurchaseDate)))<=$(=MonthEnd(max({1}PurchaseDate)))"}`

- `Monthstart(max({1}PurchaseDate)` will return the start date of the max possible date
- `MonthEnd(max({1}PurchaseDate)` will return the end date of the max possible date
- the `{1}` before `MonthStart` and `MonthEnd` functions is to `ignore all possible selections when calculating`

The result table is:

[image: Between dates]

#### Having month end field

Alternative of `between two dates` is to have another field in the table (or in the calendar table, if exists). This field will be associated with each date and will represent the month of the date. For example:

[image: table view]

In this case the expression will be:

`Sum({<PurchaseDate=, PurchaseMonth={"$(=max({1}PurchaseMonth))"}>} PurchaseVolume)`

(`PurchaseDate=` is to initially to ignore all selections in `PurchaseDate` field)

And the result of both tables will be the same:

[image: all tables]

For the record, my script is:

```
RawData:
Load
  *,
  MonthEnd(PurchaseDate) as PurchaseMonth
;
Load * Inline [
PurchaseDate, PurchaseVolume
11/01/2022  , 100
12/01/2022  , 101
13/01/2022  , 102
14/01/2022  , 103
01/02/2022  , 104
02/02/2022  , 105
03/02/2022  , 106
04/02/2022  , 107
01/05/2022  , 108
02/05/2022  , 109
03/05/2022  , 110
04/05/2022  , 111
];
```

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by using `{1} ignore all possible selections when calculating`?

Comment: Qlik allows to "put" your data in different states. The "default" state for the whole app is `$`. All set analysis is defaulting to `$` state as well. `sum( {< ... >} Sales)` and `sum( {$< ... >} Sales)` are equal and will yield the same result. Apart from `$` there is another special state and thats `1`. When using `1` in set analysis then the expression will not be affected by any selections in any state. So if you have `sum( {1< ... >} Sales)` expression then no matter what is selected across the app the expression will show the same result (as if no selections at all are made)